# Horizon detection algorithm

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

Can you help me find any information on how to detect horizon on image?
It should not be based on genetic algorithm or neural network.

Comment: do you mean boundary detection ? if yes then you can use a combination of segmentation and fourier descriptors.

Comment: @Indeera: It is stated in my question that it should not be neural network...

Comment: I meant to correct your 'nauron network'

Comment: homework ?. Can you explain why you don't want to use genetic algo's or neural networks ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just found this question interesting, so I searched the internet for you and came up with following papers/links, the first one perhaps being the most interesting, as it provides a concrete algorithm.

1. [Towards Flight Autonomy: Vision-Based Horizon Detection for Micro Air Vehicles](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.16.6951) (PDF at citeseer)
2. [Attitude Estimation for a Fixed-Wing Aircraft Using Horizon Detection and Optical Flow](http://eprints.qut.edu.au/12839/1/3067a485.pdf) (PDF)

Following the citations in the papers you will get to more resources on research in this field.

Comment: +1 Nice finds. Amazing what a little Googling turns up.

Comment: 1st and 3rd links are broken.

Comment: Fixed 1st link. Unfortunately the 3rd link is dead, as the research at the linked university has been stopped on this project.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure does this works. But my first approach would be - to detect most frequent line by using [Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) with such properties:

- line should extend up to image boundaries.
- line divides image into two regions such that in one of them standard deviation of color is small.

Answer (score 0):

Following procedure will detect horizon:-

1. Change RGB image to grayscale.
2. Find the edges in the image using **Canny edge detector**. Adjust the sigma of gaussian filter.
3. Apply **hough transform** on it.
4. Select the line segment with highest value of **J** (Equation **5**) in
   [Towards Flight Autonomy: Vision-Based Horizon Detection for Micro Air Vehicles](http://www.mil.ufl.edu/publications/fcrar02/horizon_tracking_frcar.pdf)