# Finding the Sky/Ground separation in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, detection

I am trying to detect the horizon in an image, and return a mask of the sky (or inverted as the ground).  While there seems to be many uses for it, I am battling to find a good solution.  What's worse is that it seems like such a simple problem, and most humans have NO issue in detecting the horizon.

The following makes it harder:

- The horizon is rarely a straight line in the images used (mountainous landscapes), therefore a edge detection and Hough line transform will not work.
- It needs to work in all light conditions. Thresholding (such as the Otsu thresholding) works but does not work well in low contrast conditions such as before sunrise. Fixed value thresholding does not work as the light changes too much throughout the day.

What I have tried for now is to use a colour filter limiting it to low saturations, then find contours and detect and fill the largest contour.  After this, I flood fill the area above the contour.  This does work, but I still can't imagine this problem to be so difficult.

I am writing the code in Delphi XE8, using a OpenCV wrapper, but answers or ideas in any other language are welcome!

Comment: "I am writing the code in Delphi XE8, using a OpenCV wrapper," - oh, that sounds terrible, because you probably can't use more advanced c++ features, like CLAHE or bioinspired::retina for illumination normalization

Comment: `most humans have NO issue in detecting the horizon` - most humans have some natural or learned experience in pattern recognition and scene understanding.

Comment: you probably used google already? giving me some links and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705837/horizon-detection-algorithm (which has some of the google links included again)

Comment: can you give some hints of the range where hoizons must be detected? e.g. show some sample images where you expect the algorithm to detect the horizon correctly, some border cases and some images where horizon neednt be detected.

Comment: Ok. In my case all pictures *will* have a sky in them and I want to get a rectangle of the sky only (dimensions don’t matter as long as it’s not too small). For ex:
[1](http://i.imgur.com/FE0bxbX.jpg) ([src](http://i.imgur.com/VnmWz2t.jpg)), [2 with unwanted trees (returns false)](http://i.imgur.com/h9DoMeL.jpg) ([src](http://i.imgur.com/Y3eZ9RV.jpg)), [3](http://i.imgur.com/K4WuGGk.jpg) ([src](http://i.imgur.com/lrLHV7k.jpg)), [4](http://i.imgur.com/Z4DnLSr.jpg) ([src](http://i.imgur.com/aI9d9qQ.jpg)). In fact I would be happy if we were able to detect the point of the highest ground element.

Comment: wow, that's definitely not what I expected when talking about "horizon detection" (it really is only sky detection, not horizon at all) ... can you assume that the image is always aligned, so that the sky is at the top of the image and the ground is at the bottom?

Answer (score 3):

In my understanding you are looking for a horizontal line - if exists at all - to separate the exclusively sky part from the rest.

I would compute image statistics row by row, so a horizontal histogram or similar to that.

It could be based even on a global threshold or a custom 'skyness' function. Decide somehow (intensity, hue) if pixels are sky or not and count them within scanlines.

Then half the image horizontally, sum row values for both parts and decide which direction your 'horizont line' should be moved. Half that part too and continue until you get to the proper row. With such a binary search you should be able to extract which line separates sky from foreground. If it is the first line: no sky, if last: all sky.

This problem has surely has other approaches so I am looking forward to seeing more suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is completely different. You can link OpenCV with magnetic compass to separate the sky from the ground.

You can do this in OpenCV with iOS. Link your OpenCV project with the compass which is in IPhone. Then separate the sky from the ground like what compass App did that .

See https://i.stack.imgur.com/P00oG.jpg

Comment: But if I understand what you mean, this implies that the picture you are analysing must be taken with the iPhone's camera, which as far as I understand is not what the OP is looking for. Nice creative approach though.

Comment: I know this is a bit challenging. But it worth something.

Answer (score 0):

You can try convolutional deep neural networks, like http://mi.eng.cam.ac.uk/projects/segnet/ for example, or train your own similar network.